# 2001 gt eclipse head lights both went out same time

Tags: electrical

I have check the all fuses the ,check light bulb. An they are all good. All other light work ,just not headlights. I have also  notice the interior & exterior lights go bright & dim low when i drive car

Comment: Have you checked the switch? Is there a relay fitted?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How did you go about verifying the bulbs? I mean, pretty slim chance both would go out at the same time, but sometimes the bulb can be wiley to verify. Also, do they work on high beam (or is the high beam separate)?

Comment: How did you verify that the fuse(s) that control the headlights was good?

Comment: Take it to the dealer if you can, the headlight system on that car is very complicated, it is partially run by a ETACS ECU computer, various fuses and relays and switches, diagnosis will be difficult for most people.